# connecting to a pppoe network via an ADSL2 modem

Tags: networking, home-networking, pppoe, adsl2+

I recently switched my internet provider from an ADSL2 based service to a pppoe based service. I have the old ADSL2 modem and would like to reuse it for the new PPPOE connection. The modem only has an RJ11 in, a few RJ45 out and the wifi. Is it possible to use this modem for the new service?

Currently I am not using any switch/router; I use my laptop's ethernet port directly and use windows internet connection sharing to expose the service through wifi to my other devices. It would be nice to have the ADSL modem expose the service over wifi

Answer (score 0):

PPPoE and adsl are not mutually exclusive.

Most ADSL modems will will allow for the option of configuring with PPPoE - this is simply an authentication protocol (and a few other things) that lives on top of lower level traffic. There may be specific information that you need to get from your new service provider in order to complete the modem configuration so that it will sync properly with their DSLAMs.
PPPoE will not come into play until after you've established a layer 1/2 connectivity as it is being carried on top of the ATM traffic.
You will need to ensure that you have the VPI and VCI values configured correctly (these correlate with circuit information and must match details in the DSLAM config that you are connecting to on the ISP end).

In reality, that device is 4 devices in one. It is a modem that converts ATM to Ethernet (your actual DSL connection), a router (NAT/DHCP), a wireless access point and a switch (the physical RJ45 ports). Anything connected to it via the switch portion or the wireless access point portion will be able to utilize the DSL connection through the router portion.

Comment: Thanks for giving me hope. However, I am concerned that the modem is on the outer-network side of the router while the switch and the access point are on the inner-network side of the router. As such I do not know if there is a way to configure the device so as to initiate a connection via the switch to the ISP node using the serviceID and authentication details and then expose that network over the wifi access point. Do you think a commonly available adsl/wifi device will allow such a configuration?

Comment: You are right, the modem faces the ISP, the router interfaces with the modem and provides the private facing portion - that is how all devices such as this are designed. The webui will contain configuration details for both the router portion and modem portion. Can you give us the model number so we can look up more specific details about the device you are working with?